# Verify my ER Diagram for my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm new to database and this is my first time drawing the database.
Can you guys verify if my database is corrrect?

[image: My ER Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is pretty good for a first time.  However, ER diagrams don't use arrows on connecting lines.  The only adornment used is cardinality indicators, and that only on the connections between relationship sets (diamonds) and entity sets (rectangles).  Also, while it's good that you understand that the keys of the related entities make up the key of the relationship, we don't normally show them as attributes of the relationship.